# Understanding a step in the proof of the Inverse Fourier transform theorem

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I'm trying to understand the proof of the Inverse Fourier Transform theorem in Stéphane Mallat's "A wavelet tour of signal processing". Near the end of the proof, we have:

$ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |I_\epsilon(t) - f(t)| dt = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int \int g_\epsilon(t-u) |f(u) - f(t)| du dt = 0$

where

$ I_\epsilon(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g_\epsilon(t-u) f(u) du$

and $g_\epsilon$ is a squeezed Gausian that satisfies $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int g_\epsilon(t-u) h(t) dt = \int \delta(t-u) h(t) dt = h(u)$

I don't understand the first equality in the first equation. It seems like the $g_\epsilon$ is taken out of the absolute value and I don't know how to justify this. Any pointers?

Comment: In the equation in the middle, are you sure it isn't $|f(u)-f(u)|$?

Comment: That would be after you evaluate the limit, I think. I guess it's implicit. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely, the equality would be inequality, with equality only in the limit. Such arguments almost always involve assuming that the approximate delta function satisfies
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g_{\epsilon}(t-u)du = 1.
$$
Therefore, one can move any constant (with respect to the variable of integration) inside
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g_{\epsilon}(t-u)f(u)du-f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g_{\epsilon}(t-u)(f(u)-f(t))du
$$
Then
$$
\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g_{\epsilon}(t-u)f(u)du-f(t)\right| \le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g_{\epsilon}(t-u)|f(u)-f(t)|du.
$$
Finally,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g_{\epsilon}(t-u)f(u)du-f(t)\right|dt \le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g_{\epsilon}(t-u)|f(u)-f(t)|dudt
$$
The limits of the two expressions are the same, but only because the limit on the right is 0, and the limit on the left is sandwiched between 0 and the limit on the right, which is 0. It's a sloppy way to state such a limit, because the existence of the limit on the left is being tacitly proved. A $\limsup$ would have been better, with a conclusion that the limit must actually exist and be 0.

Comment: One semi-related question. This would mean that the inverse transform is equal almost everywhere, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, assuming that $f$ falls under the inversion theorem, i.e. $\hat{f} \in L^1$. In particular, $f$ is continuous Lebesgue a.e.